# Junit External Resource @Rule Order

Tags: java, hadoop, junit, apache-pig, rule

I want to use multiple external resources in my test class, but I have a problem with ordering of external resources.

Here is code snippet :

```
public class TestPigExternalResource {

     // hadoop external resource, this should start first
     @Rule
     public HadoopSingleNodeCluster cluster = new HadoopSingleNodeCluster();

     // pig external resourcem, this should wait until hadoop external resource starts
     @Rule
     public  PigExternalResource pigExternalResource = new PigExternalResource(); 

     ...  
}
```

The problem is it tries to start pig before hadoop started, therefore I could not connect local hadoop single node cluster.

Is there any way to order rules of junit?

thanks

Comment: Is `HadoopSingleNodeCluster` class publicly available? As i use `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClusterMapReduceTestCase`, but it's not that stable.

Comment: @nefo_x **HadoopSingleNodeCluster** is my own class, not available in hadoop distribution.

Comment: is it based on some existing codebase? I try to use cluster mapreduce testcase, but it launches external JVMs and that's a bit hard for debugging in some cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [RuleChain](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html).

```
@Rule
public TestRule chain= RuleChain.outerRule(new HadoopSingleNodeCluster())
                           .around(new PigExternalResource());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap these two `ExternalResources` in your own `ExternalResource` that calls the `before` and `after` methods in the order you require from within the new resource's `before` and `after` methods.

Example:

```
public class MyResource extends ExternalResource{
     private final List<ExternalResource> beforeResources;
     private final List<ExternalResource> afterResources;

     public MyResource(List<ExternalResource> beforeResources,
          List<ExternalResource> beforeResources){
     }

      public void before(){
          for (ExternalResource er : beforeResources)
               er.before();
      }

      public void after(){
          for (ExternalResource er : afterResources)
               er.after();
      }
}


public class TestPigExternalResource {

 // hadoop external resource, this should start first
 public HadoopSingleNodeCluster cluster = new HadoopSingleNodeCluster();

 // pig external resourcem, this should wait until hadoop external resource starts
 public  PigExternalResource pigExternalResource = new PigExternalResource(); 

  @Rule
  public MyResource myResource = new MyResource(
          newArrayList(cluster, pigExternalResource),
          newArrayList(cluster, pigExternalResource));
 ...  
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I guess using @Rule annotation in before and after method is not allowed.

Comment: See example added to post. The other resources would no longer be marked as rules since they would be included in the wrapping rule.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new **order** attribute in `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` as of JUnit 4.13-beta-1.

See `@Rule` code :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Rule {

    int DEFAULT_ORDER = -1;

    /**
     * Specifies the order in which rules are applied. The rules with a higher value are inner.
     *
     * @since 4.13
     */
    int order() default DEFAULT_ORDER;

}
```

See also this PR for reference : [PR-1445](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/pull/1445).